# imap4.1: string literals. can be more than one literal on command line? can be more arguments for same command line ater string literal?

Tags: string, imap, string-literals

IMAP4.1 string literals are those prefixed with '{size_number}\r\n'.

I'm writting IMAP server implementation. Need to know more about IMAP string literals.

For instance: there is SEARCH imap command, which can have more than one string parameter. theoretically those strings can be in literal form - right? so how? could not find examples with multiple string literals on one command line in rfc3501 (or may be I've readed it to bad).

string description in rfc:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.3

there are something about Command continuation for AUTHENTICATE command
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.5
but it's seems not what I'm need.

Additional questions:

1. is there a standard server text for asking more data? - is "+ Ready for additional command text" will be ok?

Comment: The standard response from the server to signify that it is ready to receive more data is just a line beginning with a "+" token. Anything following the "+" is just free-form text (except in the case of SASL authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiple literals can occur in one command:

```
UID SEARCH SUBJECT {10}\r\n
[10 bytes] FROM {8}\r\n
[8 bytes]\r\n
```

Each literal gets its own {n}\r\n, but the command just resumes after the literal, as if it were a string (usually requiring a space).

In a client, you can see an example of this by requesting more than one body in a fetch command:

```
UID FETCH 1 (BODY[1.1] BODY[1.2])
```

The response will have two literals (assuming your body has a part 1.1 and a part 1.2).